# Loading Data to HBase from HDFS Through Apache Phoenix Using Play Java Application

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm a beginner to Hadoop technologies and I'm struggling with loading data to hbase from HDFS through Phoenix using Play Java application.

I tried to load data to hbase from HDFS through pig scripts and it works well but I couldn't find a way to do the same thing through Phoenix using Play Java application.

First, I've created a `HBase` table through Apache Phoeninx from my Play Java application but I couldn't load data (CSV file) from HDFS to that `HBase` table.

I tried the below link but didn't understand how to do it properly:

https://phoenix.apache.org/bulk_dataload.html

It would be highly appreciated, if someone can help me out with this.

--Thanks--

Comment: I think this is the link you need https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_mr.html

Comment: Yes, It is.
Thanks very much :)